# Custom Parameter Group for multiple databases RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS RDS Instance with **multiple** MySQL databases.

When I assign a Parameter group through AWS Console, it applies only to the primary database of the instance (the one created on setup wizard).

How do I attach a parameter group to a database created via MySQL CLI?

Comment: This isn't correct -- parameter groups apply to the entire RDS instance -- but I am curious why you believe that it is.

Comment: Michael, I believe because I have a table with a column CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on create. However, when I try to insert values omitting the column property, it says invalid default value. Searching the web I realized it would be solved by changing a parameter, however it doesn't. In truth I don't know if it is a problem with the fact of being a secondary database, but I really think it is. EDIT: I also rebooted the instance after applying changes.

Comment: Edit the question to add the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table, an example query and it's accompanying error, and `SELECT @@SQL_MODE;`.  Also, you might mention the parameter you were changing and the MySQL Server version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that the problem was:

I created my database and tables, then realized a problem on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on create` trigger (I was unable to insert records without specifying explicitly the date).

The problem would be solved by changing `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` parameter from one to zero, but didn't. So my first tought was to infer that the parameter only applied to the main database.

However, on `show create table` I saw that the trigger wasn't there, probably because of the parameter on time of execution.

Re-creating the table **after redefining the parameter** did the trick and the trigger worked.

Comment: So you are saying this variable can't be changed after the fact? What trigger are you talking about? You mean the default value? Very confused. Having issues with RDS not taking my change to the variable's value.